# Add custom Tab to user profile page Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to add two new tabs to the user account page at mysite.com/user on my Drupal 7 site. I want to add links to Add Photos node/add/photos and Add Videos node/add/videos but the following code for my module user_menu_add is not working for me:

```
function user_menu_add_menu() {

$items['node/add/photos'] = array(
    'title' => t('Add Photos'),
    'page callback' => 'user_menu_add',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access user menu add'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

return $items;

}
```

an example i have referenced is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192846/custom-menu-tabs-in-drupal-user-profile-page?rq=1) which works but only for links beneath the "/user" sub directory

```
function my_module_menu() {

$items['user/%user/funky'] = array(
    'title' => t('Funky Button'),
    'page callback' => 'my_module_funky',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access funky button'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

return $items;

}
```

[image: Current User Tabs]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep the `node/add/photos` menu item as is. You need to keep the URL pattern formatting like it is for the `user/%user/addphoto` in order to make the tab appear on the user profile page. However, try using [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) in your new menu item to redirect to the `node/add/photos` page.

Try this:

```
$items['user/%user/addphoto'] = array(
  'title' => t('Add Photos'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
  'page arguments' => array('node/add/photos'),
  'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

References:

- [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)
- [`user_is_logged_in()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7)
- [Drupal 7 menu system](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/group/menu/7)

Comment: Thank you! I could not figure out why Drupal wouldn't route me outside of the user profile area without this!

Answer (score 6):

I haven't enough reputation to comment an answer.
Pay attention that [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)
requires an **untranslated** title indeed the documentation says:

> ```
> "title": Required. The untranslated title of the menu item.
> ```

so the code should be

```
function my_module_menu() {
    $items['user/%user/addphoto'] = array(
      'title' => 'Add Photos',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
      'page arguments' => array('node/add/photos'),
      'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: You are correct. Specifically the value given as "title" is passed to "title callback" which defaults to [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7).